# Regarding a basic ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I solved a simple separable (and also linear) first-order ODE as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=x(1-y) \\
\frac{1}{1-y}\frac{dy}{dx}&=x \\
\int\frac{1}{1-y}\frac{dy}{dx}dx&=\int xdx \\
\ln|1-y|&=\frac{x^2}{2}+C\\
y&=1-e^{\frac{x^2}{2}+C}.
\end{align}
$$

However, online calculators suggest that the exponent in the solution is negative:
$$
y=1-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-C}.
$$

I'm sure the mistake is trivial, but I can't see it! Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the integral of $\frac{1}{1-y}$. Hint: $$\frac{d}{dy}\ln(1-y)=-\frac{1}{1-y}$$ and $$\frac{d}{dy}-\ln(1-y)=\frac{1}{1-y}$$ Everything else seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

$\int \frac{1}{1-y}dy=\int x dx$

put $u=1-y$

$\int -u^{-1} du=\int x dx$

$-\ln (u)=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$

$u=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}+ C}$

$1-y=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}+ C}$

$y=1-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}+ C}$